# Spring Integration RabbitMQ ConnectionFactory gracefully stop retry if RabbitMQ is down

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have a Configured Spring integration with RabbitMQ as message broker. I have a scenario where the application may be deployed in production with RabbitMQ down.When it happens the application continuosly tries to reconnect

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer run
WARNING: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

My server log get filled with these logs. How can I configure the connection factory, to say, try to reconnect only 5 times in interval of 10,30 or 60 mis ? 
I want to be able to control the retry and print some custom message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only a simple `recoveryInterval`, which you can increase, but it is fixed; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342007/simplemessagelistenercontainer-error-handling/28346239#28346239) has some suggestions about how to implement something more sophisticated.

Comment: Spring AMQP version 1.5 (currently at 1.5.0.M1 milestone) [now supports injecting a BackOff implementation (including exponential)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_introduction.html#_simplemessagelistenercontainer_backoff_support).