# RabbitMQ Spring Boot application handle broker down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot application configured to connect to a local RabbitMQ broker. I have also configured a `FixedBackOff` strategy in order to stop retrying connecting after 3 unsuccessful attempts.

**EDIT 1:** I have the following configuration for `FixedBackOff` as explained by @gary-russell in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28346239/3200540):

```
@Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    BackOff recoveryBackOff = new FixedBackOff(5000, 3);
    factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
    return factory;
}
```

With this configuration, I keep getting a `ConnectionException` in the console:

```
2018-04-16 13:48:29.769  WARN 54952 --- [nfoReplicator-0] o.s.b.a.health.RabbitHealthIndicator     : Health check failed

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1362)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Therefore the application does not go up and keeps on printing this exception.
How can I start this application even when the broker is down?

Answer (score 0):

That `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` is not related to what you have in the logs.

The container is about `@RabbitListener` - even-driven consumers, but here you have a `RabbitHealthIndicator` which uses already a `RabbitTemplate` and it is a passive call, therefore no any retry is applied here. Well, you can configure some retry via `spring.rabbitmq.template.retry` configuration properties, but that won't help you to stay `UP` with that health indicator meanwhile you are really `DOWN`.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that the app does not respond to HTTP request while RabbitMQ is down, would you know of any way I can overcome it and keep retrying to connect to RabbitMQ every once in a while?

Answer (score 0):

I made this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class AmqpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        ExponentialBackOff recoveryBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
        factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Using the BackOffExponencial class, your server will check whether rabbitMq is online. This service will check in exponential time and it will never stop.

Exemple:

For 10 attempts the sequence will be as follows:

request # ... back off

1 ................. 2000

2 ................. 3000

3 ................. 4500

4 ................. 6750

5 ................. 10125

6 ................. 15187

7 ................. 22780

8 ................. 30000

9 ................. 30000

10 ................. 30000